# Raw Prices vs. Daily Return vs. Price Ratio - ADF unit-root test

Tags: r, regression, cointegration, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

As the title suggests, I'd like to ask what the difference between using Raw Prices vs. Daily Return vs. Price Ratio in the Augmented Dickey-Fuller unit-root test. The context is that I am trying to find cointegrated pairs of stocks from a given time series in R.

Take a look at these three different resources, all using different metrics (Raw, Daily and Ratio) for the ADF test:
[1. Raw Prices](http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html)
[2. Daily Returns](http://gekkoquant.com/2012/12/17/statistical-arbitrage-testing-for-cointegration-augmented-dicky-fuller/)
3. Price Ratio (A UBS Research monograph, sorry couldn't find link but here is an excerpt):

> Adjusted Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test – a test of stationarity of the price ratio
>   with null hypothesis of a unit root.

Also worth noting that #3 doesn't perform linear regression (OLS), performing the ADF test on the price ratio itself, while #1 and #2 do it on the spread (residuals) of OLS. Any reason for this?

So if anyone could shed some light on the issue, that would be fantastic. Maybe it's just a matter of preference, but hopefully there are reasons for choosing them, with solid evidence backing it up to boot!

Comment: I'm also very interested in the answer to this. According to Carol Alexader's Market Risk Analysis text book series, Engle-Granger test for co-integration would use your first case of raw (well actually log) prices and that is consistent in all the literature I have read. As for your second case, the link you posted specifically say it does **NOT** use daily returns, but rather uses prices. With regards to the third case, I have seen people do this but seen no academic references  or justification and I am very interested to know if there is any!

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your reply. It's been a few weeks, I actually decided to use normalized price ratio for the test. I still do not know the advantages/disadvantages of the three. As for using daily returns in link #2, it does indeed say **not** to use it, I got confused as he uses the regression of daily returns of `A,B` to obtain `beta` :). In terms of results, it seems using Price ratio has worked well. I can provide more information if you need, the full context is that I needed to generate and select co-integrated pairs for Pairs Trading.

Comment: That's an application that I'm also looking into. If you could point me in the direction of any actual literature that supports testing for co-integration using log ratios I would greatly appreciate it. From everything I've read (very reputable sources), the correct method is either Engle-Granger which uses log prices to find residuals then ADF on those, or else Johansen which is completely different. Did you compare your co-integration selection against using Engle-Granger? To generate trade signals, are you using residuals from regression of log prices or also using the price ratio?

Comment: @Dan The literature I am following are: _Pairs Trading Performance of a Relative-Value Arbitrage Rule_,Evan Gatev 2006 and a UBS research monograph (don't think you can find this online). The only co-integration tests I did were ADF and JOH, both performing OLS on raw prices, then performing the null-hyp test on the residuals (ADF/JOH). I believe I said I used normalized prices in my previous post, that was incorrrect after reviewing my code :). So I have only compared ADF to JOH, and JOH seems to be the better option. Trade signals are determined by residuals of raw prices (mean +/- 2*sdev).

Comment: OK Thanks, so you aren't using the price ratios then. Makes sense to me.